# How to get imei on iPhone 4S?

Tags: iphone, imei

I need to get imei on iPhones.

I use https://github.com/erica/uidevice-extension/blob/master/UIDevice-IOKitExtensions.m to get IMEI.

It works fine on iphone 4, 3GS ... even with ios5.

But with iPhone 4S, imei is empty. Does somebody have a solution ?

Thank you for your answer

Answer (score 0):

If you have backup of that iPhone in iTunes, you need to
go to Preferences >> Devices, and the if you hover the
backup you should see not only IMEI number but also
Serial number and Mobile number.

You can check if that IMEI or Serial number are correct
on this website: http://sndeep.info/en

Check when your iPhone was activated on this Apple web services:
https://selfsolve.apple.com/agreementWarrantyDynamic.do

Answer (score -1):

You can easily get the IMEI by looking at the SIM card placement slot:

[image]

It should be there for the following devices:

- iPhone 7
- iPhone 7 Plus
- iPhone 6s
- iPhone 6s Plus
- iPhone 3G
- iPhone 3GS
- iPhone 4 (modello GSM)
- iPhone 4s

Source: [Apple Official Documentation](https://support.apple.com/it-it/HT204073).

Comment: the original poster wanted to retrieve the IMEI *programatically*, via code.

Answer (score -1):

**x#06#** is used for all phones. İphone 4/4s for on

Comment: the original poster wanted to retrieve the IMEI *programatically*, via code.

Answer (score -3):

you can check imei by dialing *#06# thats it