# How to get the IMEI in iPhone 4S programmatically?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I have searched in SO and Google before for this question.

I know that there is a "solution" provided by Erica but when I try it in my iPhone 4S, it simply returns empty string.

```
NSString* imei = [[UIDevice currentDevice] imei];
```

Is there anything wrong about this line? I have tried also this line and it succeeds!

```
NSString* imei = [[UIDevice currentDevice] serialnumber];
```

Similar problems:
[Problem 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8037934/how-to-get-imei-on-iphone-4s)
[Problem 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8428207/empty-imei-number-on-iphone-4s?rq=1)

Comment: NetworkController *ntc = [NetworkController sharedInstance];
NSString *imeistring = [ntc IMEI];

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/823181/how-to-get-imei-on-iphone

Comment: Please be aware that Apple has restricted access to device these properties. When calling these in app that you want to release in the AppStore you app might be rejected for using Private Frameworks.

Comment: I have tried NetworkController method but stuck in app launch. I got this:
dyld: Symbol not found: _OBJC_CLASS_$_NetworkController
  Referenced from: /var/mobile/Applications/F058B4BD-A0EF-40B0-94C7-FF2AE6D2DBF1/MyIMEI.app/MyIMEI
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in /var/mobile/Applications/F058B4BD-A0EF-40B0-94C7-FF2AE6D2DBF1/MyIMEI.app/MyIMEI

Comment: Thanks for the AppStore alert but since this app will only be distributed in Enterprise only, I think that there will not be any problem?